# Событие для window - закрытие окна (вкладки, страницы)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет!
Написал модуль под джумлу, который при закрытии вкладки со страницей сайта, выводит предупреждающее сообщение, и форму в которой пользователь указывает причину ухода с сайта.
Сделано по принципу как здесь - http://stopexit.ru/

Вопрос в том как сделать так чтобы событие закрытия window работало именно при закрытии, а не при переходе по внутренним ссылкам меню сайта...

это код с событием для window на jquery

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
if($j.cookie('sendForm')==1){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}else{
    e = e || window.event;
    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if(e){
        e.returnValue = _onbefore;
    }
    openForm();
    return _onbefore; // For Safari
}
};
```

---

Вот сайт на котором этот модуль http://g-idea.ru/, при переходах по пунктам верхнего меню, всеравно вылетает сообщение.
прочитал про это событие и когда оно срабатывает:

Действия, вызывающие данное событие

Переход на другую страницу прямо в браузере или через ссылку.
Закрытие текущего окна в браузере или закладке.
Перезагрузка текущей страницы.
Манипуляции с URL загруженной страницы с помощью объекта location в JavaScript
Метод window.navigate.
Метод window.open или document.open для открытия документа в этом же окне

Тоесть по сути все правильно работает! Но каким образом на http://stopexit.ru/demo.html при переходе по внутрениим ссылкам окно не вылетает?!

Comment: Офтоп: думаете пользователь, уходящий с сайта будет утруждать себя писаниной?
Бесполезная затея! ИМХО

Comment: А я бы запомнил адрес сайта с такой формой. =)

И никогда бы туда больше не заходил.

Comment: Да никто не спорит, мне требуется именно корректно написать код под это событие, на сайте примере при переходе по внутренним ссылкам со страницы http://stopexit.ru/demo.html окно не вылетает, но в моем коде все также как и у них, но окно вылетает(((

Answer (score 2):

Решение найдено!

Для всех ссылок при загрузке документа, присваиваем функцию по событию клика, в которой обнуляем событие для window onbeforeunload:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

    $j('a').each(function (index, value) {
        $j(this).click(function () {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        });
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {};

});
```

Comment: А потом на все сабмиты... А потом на дивы-кнопки...

Comment: Одна критика, хоть бы кто блеснул умом и предложил правильный вариант!

Comment: Возможно, это все потому, что никто бы не хотел попасть на такой сайт) Если у вас другая, более адекватная, цель, вы бы ее написали и сразу появилось бы много желающих)

Answer (score 2):

Решение с самой страницы "продукта":

```
jQuery("a, input").click(function(){window.onbeforeunload=null});
jQuery("form").submit(function(){window.onbeforeunload=null});
jQuery("select").change(function(){window.onbeforeunload=null});
jQuery("select").blur(function(){window.onbeforeunload=null});
jQuery("select").focus(function(){window.onbeforeunload=null});
window.onbeforeunload=function(e){if(getCookie('user_hash_otvet')!=false){window.onbeforeunload=null};...}
```

Короче говоря, решение совершенно не универсальное и вообще моветон:

```
jQuery("select").change(...);
jQuery("select").blur(...);
jQuery("select").focus(...);
```